# Geo Location Push Messages Exclusion List

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, geolocation, exclusion-script

Is there a way to apply an exclusion list to Geo location Push message through Salesforce Marketing cloud? Let's say I want to send anyone who is within the proximity of xyz hotel a geo location push - I also have a data extension of people how are booked that day for xyz hotel stay in Salesforce Marketing cloud and want to exclude them from my push -

Answer (score 2):

Geofence messages are cached on the device and presented immediately upon triggering a fence entry/exit, however, there is a convenience method in the Marketing Cloud MobilePush SDKs that allows you to return a boolean value representing whether or not the message should be shown ([Android](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/javadocs/6.4/reference/com/salesforce/marketingcloud/notifications/NotificationManager.ShouldShowNotificationListener.html) & [iOS](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/appledoc/Protocols/MarketingCloudSDKLocationDelegate.html)).  This would allow you to apply any custom business logic in real time.  Messages are billed when they are presented to the user so this solution should work as long as you know whether or not "this" user is "booked for today."

Comment: thanks for sharing this. Will try and let you know.

Comment: I know this can work.  The biggest deciding factor will be whether or not you have the necessary consumer data on the device when you need it :)

Comment: Thanks very much Bill!